# ponydebugger on xcode , code snippets not showing

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ponydebugger

Trying to follow this video as to how to make the ponydebugger work with my xcode project

http://cocoaheads.tv/ponydebugger-by-jay-thrash/

I'm stuck at 10:00 when he tries to drag the code snippet from the library. When I go to mine and go to Users, nothing shows up. I'm not sure if I messed up my installation.

Answer (score 0):

He created those code snippets manually in Xcode so he doesn't have to type during the demo. This isn't something that gets installed by PonyDebugger. To follow the demo, you can simply type what he drags in.

For more information on Xcode Snippets (which are awesome), see this article: http://nshipster.com/xcode-snippets/

Hope that helps!